# "more" as a target of piped command breaks bash

Tags: c, exec, pipe

Consider following source, reduced for simplicity

```
int main()
{
  int d[2];
  pipe(d);
  if(fork())
  {
    close(1);
    dup(d[1]);
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL); 
  }
  else
  {
    close(0);
    dup(d[0]);
    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL); 
  }
}
```

So it creates a pipe and redirects the output from `ls` to `cat`.

It works perfectly fine,  no problems. But change `cat` to `more` and bash breaks.

The symptoms are:

- you don't see anything you type
- pressing "enter" shows up a new prompt, but not in a new line, but in the same one
- you can execute any command and see the output
- `reset` helps fixing things up.

So there is a problem with input from keyboard, it is there, but is not visible.

Why is that?

UPDATE:

- the output from `ls | more` is equivalent to the output of my program
- `more` process does not finish, it's is orphaned by `ls`
- the only visible problem is with the state of the console after the parent process quits
- on some systems it **does** work like intended. E.g., on OpenSUSE I had no problems, on Kubuntu. I couldn't find any information on what differences should I look for, `more` binaries are different on both systems

Comment: It works fine on my system with `more` ..

Comment: Funny. On my other system it works as well. So it works on OpenSUSE, but does not on Kubuntu. That's even more deluding :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because unlike `cat`, `more` is an interactive program that requires more than `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` -- it requires a terminal, which your system call cannot provide. Try to run `more` in a pipe or from a script and see what happens.

Also note that `bash` is not involved here at any stage, the `execlp` function call replaces the current process by another one specified as an argument.

Comment: Well, `ls | more` gives me the same result as `ls | cat`, for short input. Of course I know the difference between these two. As I mention in a comment, it works as intended on SUSE, but on Kubuntu it does not. Different implementation, maybe different env? 
I have mentioned `bash` because the results are observable after the parent process is finished. The child process is still there. Why? Does it try to read the size of terminal and fails to detect that it's sufficient for the output?